# Telerik FileExplorer Example

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

I've been wrangling with creating my own File Browser Content Provider for Telerik's FileExplorer control. They have one example on their website, but it hasn't helped my solve some ASP.NET Page and UserControl life-cycle issues I've been having.

Is there better example out there of using the FileExplorer control with a custom Content Provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this link:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer/examples/dbfilebrowsercontentprovider/defaultcs.aspx

You can search forum if you are facing any issues from the telerik forum.

just like following link

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/search.aspx?rtf=Forum&start=0&q=%2bFile%2bBrowser%2bContent%2bProvider%2b

Here is the telerik forum:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx. You can select product you have and search for problem that you are facing. They will also give additional example If you request them via a ticket.

Comment: Thanks. The demo was the example I was referring to. I've also posted to the forums this morning (I just get a quicker response from stackoverflow).

Comment: Apparently,  the lack of documentation for the FileExplorer control is widely complained about. Telerik released a new SP today that will hopefully have better documentation.